# How do I read in a local text file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, file-io

I am trying to use  to select a file locally and read the text in it line by line to interpret it. My program is meant to read a text file and read questions from it to make a test taking program. The file should not be uploaded, and only read locally. It is okay if the solution only works on chrome and firefox.

I have tried looking through many things, but so far what I seem to see is that it is not possible for security reasons, or it is but it doesn't work properly. I

This is my current code:
http://pastebin.com/uKvEfvZZ

Comment: Hiya, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466387/read-2-text-files-with-javascript ; cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [HTML5 file API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications). It allows you to select and read files locally.

Comment: That is actually what I had tried before. It didn't seem to work properly.

Comment: It is supported in modern browsers only. Check xdazz's demo

Comment: this works, but not locally (on chrome atleast). I forgot to update everyone on that. When i tried it on a webhost it was perfectly fine.

Comment: @user1276567 for accessing local files in Chrome you must start Chrome with this switch: chrome --disable-web-security

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bHfEk/).

html:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />
```

js:

```
function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
    //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
    var files = evt.target.files;

    if (files) {
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function (f) {
                return function (e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    alert(contents);
                };
            })(f);
            r.readAsText(f);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Failed to load files");
    }
}
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);​
```

Comment: I used code similar to this before, apparently I had some errors. This helped alot, thank you!

Comment: Great example written in pure JS! Thanks