# set an onclick event watcher within an onchange event processing possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I saw a post [How do I read in a local text file with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756411/how-do-i-read-in-a-local-text-file-with-javascript)

I want to add a button to simulate an upload.  So my consideration is set a watcher to onclick in onchange processing, is it possible?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHfEk/)

**js**

```
function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
//Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
var files = evt.target.files;

if (files) {
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        alert(f);
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = (function (f) {
            return function (e) {
                var contents = e.target.result;
                alert(contents);
            };
        })(f);
        r.readAsText(f);
      }
    } else {
      alert("Failed to load files");
    }
}
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);
```

**html**

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />
```

Comment: so what is the problem? - the fiddle seems to be reading the file

Comment: I want to add a button, when click shows alert message.

Comment: So... what's blocking you from adding the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the change handler, add a button and add a click handler

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" multiple />
<button id="read">Read</button>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function readMultipleFiles(input) {
        //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
        var files = input.files;

        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                var r = new FileReader();
                r.onload = (function (f) {
                    return function (e) {
                        var contents = e.target.result;
                        alert(contents);
                    };
                })(f);
                r.readAsText(f);
            }
        } else {
            alert("Failed to load files");
        }
    }

    var fileIn = $('#fileinput')[0];
    $('#read').click(function () {
        readMultipleFiles(fileIn)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PbAPD/)